# How to move the cursor/caret inside a input field with arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, dom-events

I need a way to move the cursor/caret inside a input field (character by character) with the arrow keys (ArrrowLeft, ArrowRight) on a keydown event.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
  const handleKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      e.stopPropagation();

      e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(
        e.currentTarget.value.length,
        e.currentTarget.value.length - 1,
      );

      e.currentTarget.focus();
    }
  };

  return <MyCustomInputField onKeyDown={handleKeyDown)/>;
```

This way on a single `keydown` on the arrow left key the cursor/caret gets moved to the left by two characters and that's it. Any other keydown event has no effect.

What am I doing wrong here or whats missing?

---

**Little update:**

This way it works for the `ArrowRight` key, but if I press the `ArrowLeft` key the cursor/caret moves to the left by two characters...

```
if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(
    e.currentTarget.selectionStart,
    e.currentTarget.selectionStart - 1,
  );
  e.currentTarget.focus();
}

if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(
    e.currentTarget.selectionStart,
    e.currentTarget.selectionStart + 1,
  );
  e.currentTarget.focus();
}
```

Comment: Moving the cursor with the arrow keys within an input field is standard functionality. What do you want to do? However, your code only checks for the `ArrowLeft` key.

Comment: It's not a standard functionality in my use case. It's a custom input field inside a complex component. For my question I just simplified it. As mentioned I want to move the cursor character by character with the arrow keys.

Comment: It is standard functionality. I guess thats the reason you want to get it working. I suspect your custom complex component is somehow stopping this from working. Please create a [mre] so we can check.

Comment: `setSelectionRange` sets the text selection not the cursors position. It's like two cursors.

Comment: I solved it for now and added an answer to my question. Let my know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this for now *(these snippets are placed inside custom methods, since I refactored a little bit)*

**For arrow left**

```
currentTarget.setSelectionRange(
  currentTarget.selectionStart,
  currentTarget.selectionStart - 1,
);
```

**For arrow right**

```
currentTarget.setSelectionRange(
  currentTarget.selectionStart,
  currentTarget.selectionStart + 1,
);
```

For the arrow left `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` was needed.

For the arrow right only `e.stopPropagation()` was enough.

Additionally I could remove the `e.currentTarget.focus()` completely.

What do you think?